# Snakemake rule for analysis where a single result file is produced for diff parameters, and parameter is coming from another rule output content

Tags: python, snakemake

I have the following basic snakemake setup:

```
rule step1:
    """
    The output will contain a list of GENEs in a txt file.
    """

    input: "input1.txt"

    output: "output1.txt"

    shell:
        """
        analysis1.R {input} {output}
        """

rule step2:
    """
    Analysis step2.
    """

    input: "input2.txt"

    output: "output2.txt"

    shell:
        """
        analysis2.py {input} {output}
        """

rule step3:
    """
    GENE should be coming from the step1 output file, with a GENE name on each
    line.
    """

    input: rules.step2.output

    output: "output3-GENE.txt"

    shell:
        """
        analysis3.py -i {input} -o {output} -p GENE
        """
```

I produce a file with a list of genes (parameters) in step1 for step3 and another file in step2. What I would like to do is run step3 as many times as lines I have in `output1.txt` where the content of the line is a parameter for step3, and it should also be part of the output file name, but I can't wrap my head around it. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution).

If you know the list of files that your `step3` file shall generate, you may define an `aggregate` rule:

```py
rule aggregate:
    input:
        # List of files that step3 needs to generate
```

That would allow you to run the `rule step3` as many times as is needed.

The tricky part is to define the list of these files. That shall be the function of the result of the `rule step1`:

```py
def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    with checkpoints.rile1.get().output[0].open() as f:
        return f.readlines()

rule aggregate:
    input:
        aggregate_input
```

In this case the `rule step1` shall become a checkpoint:

```py
checkpoint step1:
    """
    The output will contain a list of GENEs in a txt file.
    """

    input: "input1.txt"

    output: "output1.txt"

    shell:
        """
        analysis1.R {input} {output}
        """
```

In my example I've simplified the function `aggregate_input` to return just the lines of the output of `step1`. If you need a more complex function, you may design your own one.

Comment: Yes, a checkpoint and a function did it. Although I added at the end of rule1 a `split -l` statement so each gene name had its own file, and the function listed/modified all of these files for the aggregate rule input.